# Unit sphere of a norm is a submanifold implies the norm is smooth?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, norms, smoothness

Let us call a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ **smooth** if its restriction $\| \cdot \|:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth map.

Suppose the unit sphere of a norm $\| \cdot \|$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is $\| \cdot \|$ necessarily smooth?

**Remark:**

The converse statement is easy:

Assume $\| \cdot \|$ is smooth. Then it's a submersion (considered as a map $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{R}$). To see it's differential is nonzero just note that $df_x(x)=\|x\|$. So, the unit sphere is an inverse image of a regular value.

Comment: See answer to 1) here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/223933/questions-about-the-regularity-of-the-norm-associated-to-a-convex-set/224432#224432

Comment: Thanks. If I understood correctly your answer, it also implies that if the unit sphere is a $C^k$ submanifold (hypersurface) , the norm is also $C^k$. (and similarly for $C^{\infty}$).

Comment: Yes, that's right.